# What are the differences between the Home and Business editions of Office 365?

Tags: office-365

There appear to be two editions of Office 365 with coparable price points, [Office 365
Home](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/buy/compare-microsoft-office-products-FX102898564.aspx) and [Office 365 Small Business Premium](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans-FX102918419.aspx). Is there a comparison chart that compares all editions side by side, along with any restrictions for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [fairly neat comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_365#Comparison) of all the various editions and features.

Comment: For the record, according to Microsoft's pre-sales team, the Business-class email refers to a hosted Exchange account, and is not available with the "Home" range of products (other than what you can do for free with outlook.com)